# Cannot resolve method addOnCompleteListener when I used Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I try works with Firebase Cloud Messaging and I'v some problems. 
I wrote code for suscribe to topic but when I'm use in addOnCompleteListener I get this error:

> Cannot resolve method 'addOnCompleteListener(live.jtube.app.MassegeNetsActivity, anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener)'

here part of my code:

MassegeNetsActivity.java code:

```
 .....
 import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
 import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.IntentFilter;
 ..... 

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.massege_nets);

  FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("weather")
          .addOnCompleteListener(MassegeNetsActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() { //here i got the error
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    String msg = "תהליך הרשמה לערוץ בוצע בהצלחה!";
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        msg = "אופס! תהליך הרישום לערוץ נכשל, אנא בדוק את החיבור שלך לאינטרנט";
                    }
                   // Log.d(TAG, msg);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
      ......
```

and here build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.app.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 34
        versionName "4.17"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //firebase
    //firebase analytics
    // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'//firebase Cloud Messaging
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'

    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I searched on google almost 3 hours and i can't find any answer that will work...

can you help me?

thank you very much!

Comment: Hey you won't be able to do that because subscribeToTopic() returns an instance of type Task which doe not has a method addOnCompleteListener

Comment: @mohdshoaib but in google example: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/c63f28bef62f8522c37abef84bde30931101d9e2/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MainActivity.java#L79-L90 they do like me...

Comment: I see. Sorry brother, then no Idea. Probably check the version of the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked in your comment only passes in an `OnCompleteListener`, while your code passes in an additional `MassegeNetsActivity.this` as the argument before that. While there is a `addOnCompleteListener` that takes two arguments, in that overload the first parameter is an `Executor`, and it seems that an `Activity` instance is not a valid `Executor` object.

The solution is to call the `addOnCompleteListener` with just the listener:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("weather")
          .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    ...
```

Comment: If you still get the same error, it didn't come from the code you modified. While you may still get **an** error, it won't be the same, so please show the updated error message.

Comment: in compiler i get this error "error: void cannot be dereferenced" and when I cover with my mouse the "addOnCompleteListener" I see this message: Cannot resolve method 'addOnCompleteListener(anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<java.lang.Void>)' thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, that method (unlike the one you previously tried to use) is defined right herE: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E). I wonder if you're pulling in a wrong library, but unfortunately can't help further with that. Maybe somebody else sees what's going wrong now.